# Entity framework, custom model, datgrid, paging, sorting not working

Tags: asp.net, webforms, entity-framework-5

I am using vs 2012, .net 4.5, entity framework 5, web forms, vb (but c# help just as good for me)

I am new to using the Entity framework. I have decided to create a new project in .net 4.5 so i can use item Type for strongly typed data controls, in this case gridview.

I need to retrieve data from multiple tables 5+, which by its self is easy enough, but this means i cant use EntityDataSource as theres no option to build a query etc only select a single table. How can i achieve this plesae? I guess in the code behind i can set the gridview datasource but then do i need to implement custom paging and sorting?

I presume in this case i wont be able to use a strongly typed data control but i can live with that, does that mean its only viable for getting data from 1 table. Or do i need to populate my model with all results. The amount of data in the tables is well over 500,000 rows so obviously it has to be paged! And the page has a number of filters / search otpions

I am at a loss here, mainly i obviously am not understanding something.

I have been researching / googling this for a few hours som findings are below, but again they dont really answer or help me.

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/03/26/asp-net-4-5-web-forms-features-strongly-typed-data-controls.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1677303.aspx/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is creating a view with whatever you want in your database and then regenerating your EDMX to include the view.  You will then have a strongly typed object designating the fields in the View.

Comment: good point i never though of that. What about filtering, paging sorting etc. The filters / where clause is very dynamic based based on login type and there are about 10 filters. Thanks